# Does rsyncing a Linux boot disk require any caveats to run off the copy?

Tags: boot, software-raid, raid-1, centos-7

The new server to run CentOS7 is on order. It will have a 60 GB SSD for CentOS 7 and four internal hard drives. The internal hard drives will run in a software RAID1 for three disk mirroring plus the forth drive will be a hot spare.

With the 60 GB SSD being the boot device for CentOS 7, can this be rsync to the internal drives so in the event there is a failure on the SSD, the BIOS can select to boot from /dev/mdX which contains the rsync'ed OS?

Does this cause any complications or concerns that might break the software RAID 1 or anything else? Would some changing of the configuration files be needed for this to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

When you do the rsync backup of the Linux boot device, make sure you leave out things like /tmp, so it doesn't create any confusion. Otherwise, I don't see a problem with doing this.